# Don't render bitrix component

Tags: php, components, bitrix

I try to include this component.

```
<? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "mycompany:schedule",
    "",
    Array(
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "COL1" => "Direction",
    "COL2" => "Airline",
    "COL3" => "Flight",
    "COL4" => "Departure",
    "COL5" => "Arrival",
    "COL6" => "Days of the week",
    "COL7" => "Navigation",
    "COL8" => "Aircraft type",
    "FILTER_TITLE1" => "Point of departure",
    "FILTER_TITLE1_2" => "Destination",
    "FILTER_TITLE2" => "Flight number",
    "FILTER_TITLE3" => "Departure date",
    "FILTER_TITLE4" => "Carrier",
    "FILTER_TITLE5" => "Departure",
    "FILTER_TITLE6" => "Arrival",
    "FILTER_TITLE7" => "Aircraft timetable",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "19",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "scoreboard",
    "ICOL1" => "Departure Airport",
    "ICOL2" => "Destination airport",
    "ICOL3" => "Arrival",
    "ICOL3_2" => "Departure",
    "ICOL4" => "Type of aircraft",
    "ICOL5" => "Airline",
    "ICOL6" => "Representative contacts",
    "ICOL7" => "Route",
    "LANGUAGE" => "ru",
    "LINKS1_IBLOCK_ID" => "8",
    "LINKS1_IBLOCK_TYPE" => "content",
    "LINKS1_SECTION_ID" => "322",
    "LINKS2_SECTION_ID" => "321",
    "NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE" => "Nothing found. Change filter options"
    )
);?>
```

If LANGUAGE is ru or some else - all it's ok
if LANGUAGE is en - browser render empty document withous any scripts or style, nothing.

If i set the languege in the component's code, all it is ok.
 Where the problem?

Comment: I think it's empty, cause in params your `"LANGUAGE"` key is always has 'ru' value. Try to define LANGAUGE key like this: `'LANGUAGE' => $language,` where `$language` defines in session or wherever you need.

Comment: "mycompany:schedule" is not standard component, go to source code and check what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the trouble.

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2830

In the component.php infinity loop.

Answer (score 0):

You simply got 500 response. In such cases just enable error reporting and you'll see error message with file name and line number